# Haskell: Serial received data not printed correctly

Tags: haskell, arduino, serial-port

I'm trying to receive data from my Arduino `Serial.println("No Format");`. When I open arduino-serial-monitor I can see the output how I wanted it.

```
No Format
No Format
...
```

I use  [serialport package.](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/serialport-0.4.7/docs/System-Hardware-Serialport.html) But the output printed on ghci is:

```
*Main> main
"\r\nNo Forma"
"t\r\nNo Form"
"at\r\nNo For"
"mat\r\nNo Fo"
"rmat\r\nNo F"
"ormat\r\nNo "
"Format\r\nNo"
" Format\r\nN"
"o Format\r\n"
...
...
"\nNo"
" For"
"mat\r"
"\nNo "
"Form"
"at\r\n"
....
```

---

*Haskell:*

```
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as B
import System.Hardware.Serialport
import System.IO
import Control.Monad

main :: IO ()
main = forever $ do
  let port = "/dev/ttyACM0"
  s <- openSerial port SerialPortSettings { commSpeed = CS9600,
                                            bitsPerWord = 8,
                                            stopb = One,
                                            parity = NoParity,
                                            flowControl = NoFlowControl,
                                            timeout = 10 }
  recv s 10 >>= print
  closeSerial s
```

---

*Arduino:*

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  Serial.println("No Format");
}
```

Any help would be awesome. Thanks.

Comment: Try using `putStr` instead of `print`.  You may also need to flush stdout or change the buffering mode to `LineBuffering`

Comment: Also, you are opening and closing the serial port for every 10 characters.  Is this really what you want to do?

Comment: @pat : Your second comment is the right one. "\r\nNo Forma" is indeed a ByteString of length 10.

The ByteString should probably be parsed into a String (perhaps even using the scary Data.ByteString.Char8, depending on need)

Comment: It's serial without a notion of start and end of the frame. So you are just off by 1 character.

Comment: @Sarah Opening and closing the port so often is inefficient, but shouldn't change the meaning of the program much. pat's first comment is much more important in terms of matching the behavior he wants, in my opinion.

Comment: Using `B.putStr` fixed it. Thanks @pat!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `B.putStr` instead of `print` fixed the problem.
Thanks to @pat.

Answer (score 2):

You could just receive characters until you receive a "\n" character. Maybe something like this:

```
import Control.Monad (forever)
import Control.Applicative ((<$>))
import Data.ByteString.Char8 (unpack)
import System.Hardware.Serialport (SerialPort, openSerial, recv)

-- Read a character from the serial port.
receive :: SerialPort -> IO String
receive sp = fmap unpack (recv sp 1)

-- Read a line, ending with '\n'.
readLine :: SerialPort -> IO String
readLine sp = readLineRec sp [] 

-- Recursive function to read a line from the serial port.
readLineRec :: SerialPort -> String -> IO String
readLineRec sp [] = receive sp >>= readLineRec sp 
readLineRec sp chars
    | last chars == '\n' = return chars
    | otherwise = (chars ++) <$> receive sp >>= readLineRec sp

main = do
    let port = "/dev/ttyACM0"
    s <- openSerial port SerialPortSettings { commSpeed = CS9600,
                                        bitsPerWord = 8,
                                        stopb = One,
                                        parity = NoParity,
                                        flowControl = NoFlowControl,
                                        timeout = 10 }
    forever $ do
        line <- readLine s
        print line
```

There is room for improvement, but it works!

Comment: Thanks Elie. This is certainly a very useful answer.